# How do I use TabbedView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, ios13

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabbedView {
                PasswordGenerator()
                    .tabItemLabel {
                        Image("KeyGlyph")
                        Text("Generator")
                }

                PasswordGeneratorSettings()
                    .tabItemLabel {
                            Image("SettingsGlyph")
                            Text("Settings")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This won't compile but it was used in the Swift Essentials video at WWDC (See minute 54:30) and I've seen some workarounds like the VStack workaround (but even that has many flaws, the left tab is too far to the left and the right tab is too far to the right and when switching tabs only the first one that initially loaded loads and the other tab stays blank and using tags doesn't help). So how do I have two tabs that load the views and have an Image and Text?

Comment: Do you have macOS Catalina?

Comment: @Lu_ Yes I do have macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With XCode beta 3 the following should work:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home : View {
    @State private var currentTab = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $currentTab) {
            FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                        Text("First Tab")
                    }
                }.tag(1)
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                        Text("Second Tab")
                    }
                }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Enclosing the tab label in a `VStack` seems to be optional, though. So, you might decide to drop this, like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home : View {
    @State private var currentTab = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $currentTab) {
            FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    Text("First Tab")
                }.tag(1)
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    Text("Second Tab")
                }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i have a tab item with only an image, how can i change its position or alignment ?

Answer (score 10):

For those still searching for how to do this, here's an update with Xcode 11 GM.

```swift
struct Tabs: View {

    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            MyFirstView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 0 ? "star.fill" : "star"))
                    Text("One")
                }.tag(0)
            MySecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 1 ? "star.fill" : "star"))
                    Text("Two")
                }.tag(1)
            MyThirdView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: (selected == 2 ? "star.fill" : "star"))
                    Text("Three")
                }.tag(2)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // Important if you want NavigationViews to go under the status bar...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I have the exact problem using TabView and navigation view. However, if I set .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all), I would have everything expanded out of screen. How do I fix that?

Comment: Try edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom]) or possibly you want just .top ( depends on your View)

Answer (score 10):

`TabbedView()` has been deprecated use `TabView()` instead.

Using integers to select views smells bad to me, from my days working with `tag()` of UIButton and UIView, it is better to enumerate what you are doing rather than assign a hard coded values that have a very large range. i.e. `Int.min()` to `Int.max()`. This also makes code easier to read and maintain in the future.

`TabView(selection: )` can be used to select the index, and is declared as:

```
public struct TabView<SelectionValue, Content> : View where SelectionValue : Hashable, Content : View {
    public init(selection: Binding<SelectionValue>?, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
…
```

This means that you can select the index with any hashable content.

We can use a `enum` that conforms to `Hashable` to contain a list of tabs,
In this way can use an Observable later to help control and load state of the view. Or have the enum as part of the state of your app. I am sure there are plenty of resources you can use to find an appropriate solution that meets your needs.

```
 struct MainTabView: View {

 @State private var selection: Tabs = .profile

 private enum Tabs: Hashable {
     case content
     case profile
 }

 var body: some View {

    TabView(selection: $selection) {

        // Learn Content
        Text("The First Tab")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "book")
                Text("Learn")
        }.tag(Tabs.content)


        // The Users Profile View.
        ProfileView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                Text("Profile")
        }.tag(Tabs.profile)
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code *should* work, however this is a known issue, from [iOS & iPadOS 13 Beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_2_release_notes):

> The tabItemLabel(_:) modifier doesn’t accept @ViewBuilder closures.

The only workaround, until this is fixed, is to use VStack as you've mentioned.

```
MyView()
    .tabItemLabel(VStack {
        Image("resourceName")
        Text("Item")
    })
```

---

### Update:

This issue was fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 3**:

> The tabItemLabel(*:) modifier — now named tabItem(*:) — now accepts
>   @ViewBuilder closures.

Example:

```
.tabItem {
    Image(systemName: "circle")
    Text("Tab1")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TabbedView was deprecated.

You could use *[TabView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview)* instead now

```
struct AppTabbedView: View {
    @State private var selection = 3

    var body: some View {
        TabView (selection:$selection){
            Text("The First Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")

            }
            .tag(1)
            Text("Another Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
            }.tag(2)
            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Third")
            }.tag(3)
        }
        .font(.headline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as of Xcode 11 GM, this code works: (from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview)

```html
TabView {
    Text("The First Tab")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
            Text("First")
        }
    Text("Another Tab")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
            Text("Second")
        }
    Text("The Last Tab")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
            Text("Third")
        }
}
.font(.headline)
```

Answer (score 1):

TabbedView is deprecated and has been renamed to TabView
You can use TabView like this

```
TabView {
    (Text("Tab 1!").tabItem {
         Text("First")
    })
    (Text("Tab 2!").tabItem {
         Text("Second")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'TabbedView' can be used in a way similar to the following:

```swift
    struct TabView : View {

        @State private var selection = 1

        var body: some View {
            TabbedView (selection: $selection) {
                InboxList()
                    .tabItemLabel(selection == 1 ? Image("second") : Image("first"))
                    .tag(1)

                PostsList()
                    .tabItemLabel(Image("first"))
                    .tag(2)

                Something()
                    .tabItemLabel(Image("first"))
                    .tag(3)
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why your example doesn't compile but you miss both the `selection` param and the `.tag` property on each "tab".

Btw in the current XCode version (beta 2) you cannot show both a text and an image as label.